# ASP.NET Core misconfigured Nuget package dependency - Unexpected package version warnings

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have an asp.net core project, which was working great few day earlier. I have it on github in a private repo. Yesterday it stopped working after installing an update from VS. I have searched all over the net and github, can't find any solution to this. The image of warning i am getting is attached. The warning description is as follows from Microsoft,

> NU1603
>       **Issue** A package dependency specified a version that could not be found. A 
>       higher version was used instead, which differs from what the package was 
>       authored against.
>       This means that restore did not find the best match. Each restore will float 
>       downwards trying to find a lower version that can be used. This means that 
>       restore goes online to check all sources each time instead of using the 
>       packages that already exist in the user package folder.
>       **Common causes**   The package sources do not contain the expected lower bound 
>       version. If the package expected has not been released then this may be a 
>       package authoring error.
>       **Example message** NuGet.Packaging 4.0.0 depends on NuGet.Versioning (>= 4.0.0) 
>       but 4.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of 5.0.0 was resolved.

I don't know how can i solve this ? it seems there is no solution out there, I have even reinstalled VS, cleared nuget cache, deleted packages from global folder but my solution isn't working.

Any help in regard will be highly appreciated.

[image: VS Warning Message]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have NuGet 4.3 with VS 2017 15.3.
The coded NuGet warnings and errors are part of the 15.3 release which is basically the NuGet.exe 4.3 release.

Basically you have 2 options to solve this issue:

1. Fixing the dependency tree by manually updating `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` package with version 4.1.0 or higher
2. Use `NoWarn` to ignore/suppress this warning like [described here](https://blog.nuget.org/20170815/Whats-nu-in-NuGet-with-VS2017-15-3.html#msbuild-integration-of-nuget-warnings-and-errors), by editing you `csproj` file like below.

   `<PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" Version="4.0.0">
         <NoWarn>NU1603</NoWarn>
   </PackageReference>`

Comment: @AftabAhmed Try to  just update `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui. It should help.

Comment: @user2771704 Is there any way to fail build when exact version is not found?

Answer (score 1):

i know this old ticket and i was getting the same issue. However the accepted answer did not solve in my case.   so what i did was:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete all "bin" and "obj" folders for all projects
3. Delete all Castle.* folder in the C:\Users[user acc].nuget\packages\Castle.*
4. Open Visual Studio, Clean Solution, and then Rebuild

Comment: Did step by step, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress these warnings for all package references in a given project, add/modify your *.csproj to include `NU1603` under the `PropertyGroup` tag for each target you want to suppress it under.

Here is an example:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;NU1603</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;NU1603</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As mentioned by @user2771704 this is documented [here](https://blog.nuget.org/20170815/Whats-nu-in-NuGet-with-VS2017-15-3.html#msbuild-integration-of-nuget-warnings-and-errors).